# On a custom object I get this error on Conga Composer button: The id parameter is missing

Tags: object, conga

I have this URL for my button on my custom object "Parts"

```
https://composer.congamerge.com?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl=
{!API.Partner_Server_URL_290} &id={!Parts__c.Id}
```

when I click the button on the parts list view, I get the error that the id parameter is missing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is the ID in the url when you click the button? If not try removing the space before the `&id=`

Answer (score 2):

Conga Composer URLs are notoriously sensitive to copy paste errors where you inadvertently do things like this formatting structure:

```
https://composer.congamerge.com?
sessionId={!API.Session_ID}
&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290} 
&id={!Parts__c.Id}
```

in order to make the buttons readable in the SFDC point-and-click UI.

If you copy and paste from a detail page of a custom button, the copy paste operation will insert a non-visible space at the end of every line.

I always clicked Edit on a composer button and then did the copy before pasting into a second button's Edit window.  This avoids the inadvertent trailing space.

Should you need a real space in the URL, use the `+` character to represent a space.  For example, `&DV0=foo+bar` to assign the `DV0` parameter to `foo bar`.